# Heron formula in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make Heron formula and semiperimeter with 3 sides functions and return JavaScript down and a+b>c and in forms to add numbers? It must enter numbers in forms not letters.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
    <body>
<script>
        function area(A, B, C) {
            var D;
            D = Math.sqrt ( ( ( A + B + C ) / 2 ) - A ) * ( ( ( A+ B + C ) / 2 ) - B ) * ( ( ( A + B + C ) / 2 ) - C );
            return D;
        }

        var x = area(3,4,5);
        document.write(x);

        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is a clear question. What does your code do now and what problem are you experiencing in particular?

Comment: Don't you know how the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) goes?

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little unclear but it seems you are asking for Heron's formula in Javascript?

Herons formula = `A = \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}` ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula))

So:

```
function area(a, b, c, s) {
    return Math.sqrt(s*((s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)))
}
```

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

 
 <body>
   
<form>
 First number:  <input type="number" element_id="A"><br>
 Second number: <input type="number" element_id="B"><br>
 Third number: <input type="number" element_id="C"><br>
 <script>
  function area(A, B, C) {
   var D
        D = A + B + C;
   return D;
  }

  </script>
  <button type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>

Comment: Perimeter: <input type="number" element_id="D"><br>
 Area: <input type="number" element_id="E">
function area(a, b, c, s) {
    return Math.sqrt(s*((s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)))
}

</body>
</html>

Comment: and i want number string  val == Number(val) with  and return in labels for area and perimter and i want add 2 sides bigger than 3 side in javascript

Comment: gdx my code for area and perimter and no work to calculate area and perimeter

Comment: Is this homework? And I'm at my limit of understanding broken English. Trying not to be rude but I simply cannot understand what more you want.

Comment: yes and need help for me cuz i don't know javascript and can't resolve it  i tried many things

Comment: i want html forms and i want calculate from html form the  area and perimeter triangle with heron formula and i need to check A + B > C && B + C > A && C + A > B  and values from a b c  to be numbers not letters added my people and if people add letters not numbers they will give result 0  or can't introduce letters by prompt and  val == Number(val)

Comment: please help me.

Answer (score 0):

[Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula).

```js
function area( a, b, c ) {
  const s = (a + b + c) / 2
  return Math.sqrt( s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c) )
}

document.write(area(3,4,5))
```